# Shell bash completion window

Tags: completion, shell-mode

I am in `shell-mode` with `bash-completion` enabled. When I attempt tab completion, Emacs creates a new window to display completions.

For example, if I am in a directory with subdirectories `foo` and `foobar`, and I type `cd foo TAB`, Emacs will open a new buffer with the following contents:

```
Click on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
foo/
foobar/
```

If I <kbd>C-x o</kbd> into the other window and select a completion, then the window disappears. However, that takes a few keystrokes, so sometimes I end up instinctively completing the path myself. If I do that, the window sticks around.

How can I improve this workflow so that my shell stops generating extra windows? I didn't want to make this an XY problem, but I can think of a few ways. One idea would be to hide the window if I keep typing. Something better would be to hook the completion results into `ido`.

Comment: Do you really mean "Emacs creates a new frame"? (See [Frames](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frames.html#Frames) in the manual.) I think you mean "Emacs creates a new [window](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows.html#Windows).

Comment: @Constantine, you're absolutely right. I still get them confused sometimes.

Comment: I would give [ido-ubiquitous](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous) a try. (It is not shell-specific, but does promise to do what you need.)

Comment: As it turns out, I have `ido-ubiquitous-mode` already active. Deactivating it does not seem to affect the problematic behavior.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to try out [company-mode](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode). It has a built-in backend `company-capf` which fetches completion candidates from emacs' `completion-at-point-functions` (the same mechanism that powers completion in the shell) as such completion offered by company are as accurate as the built-in shell-mode while making the user interface is very convenient.

You can activate it as follows

```
(eval-after-load "shell"
  '(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "TAB") #'company-complete))
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook #'company-mode)
```

Notice that I have rebound <kbd>tab</kbd> to `company-complete` so that hitting tab pops up company completion menu rather than the built-in completions buffer.

[Ehvince](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/739/ehvince) has put a nice screenshot on [wikiemacs](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Shell#Shell_completion_with_a_nice_menu_.C3.A0_la_zsh) about the above in action

Another option is to use `helm`, if you enable helm by doing `(helm-mode +1)` it replaces the default completion mechanism with its own more pleasant completion system.

Comment: OMG I didn't know about that this is mindblowing !!!

Comment: Here a screenshot of the result: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Shell#Shell_completion_with_a_nice_menu_.C3.A0_la_zsh

Comment: Don't use `define-key` in a hook. It's sufficient to bind the key once.  Also, `company-complete` is probably a better function for that key.

Comment: @lunaryorn valid points, I do not remember why I used `company-manual-begin` in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

This is a subset of your question, but it should help in that the following code may be extended to serve larger purposes and that I share my investigations.

I asked [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952995/emacs-shell-change-directory-with-ido) about **changing directory with ido**. Someone answered, which maybe @iqbal-ansari will recognize, and I put the resulting code into a repo which I called [fasd-shell](https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/fasd-shell). The goal was to cd as fast as possible, so the process is this (all help in above  link):

- install the fasd command line utility
- install fasd-shell
- and to use it: type `d foo` (`d` followed by a space) to trigger the fasd engine and the ido completion, which will ask you to cd to any directory containing `foo` in its full name *that you already visited with an explicit cd*.

So `d` triggers an action that calls ido for the completion. So we're not limited to `d` and `cd`, we could recognize any pattern and fire any action. (I'm nearly done for `makefile`s' targets completion)

I tried to put it on MELPA so I got a review and I've been asked to use either a `completion-at-point` function or to hook into `pcomplete` (`pcmplt-*`), instead of re-defining `TAB`.

So here I am.